# Create and verify sha-512 password hashes with crypt() and PHP

Tags: php, hash

The PHP function `crypt()` creates a hash for a password. It requires a second parameter for a random salt. This salt can also include additional instructions about which algorithm to use. Seems like a hack, but that's the API. So I add the `$6$` prefix to get the SHA-512 hash I need. (Can't use bcrypt for the external non-PHP application that shall also be able to verify the hash. The hash must be verified from PHP and other applications with limited algorithms support.)

Now there are two problems that the PHP manual leaves me alone with:

1) Where do I get a random salt and what requirement does it need to satisfy? I've read about `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` and I thought I'd just base64-encode it. But how many source bytes or encoded characters do I need?

2) How can I verify such a hash in PHP again? There doesn't seem to be a single function to do that. I believe I can call `crypt` again with the same salt as before, but to do that, I need to extract the hash and algorithm and whatever else is needed from the stored password hash. I've seen hashes with variable number of $ characters, so that doesn't seem like a good delimiter to split by.

I've read about phpass but it doesn't support sha-512, so I can't use that.

PHP version is 5.5.9 so some functions may not be available.

Comment: Why don't you use PHP's built-in [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to do all the work for you? And [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) for verification. That's what it was written for.

Comment: I'd love to, but it only supports bcrypt, not sha512crypt or anything else.

Comment: password_hash() is the recommended option for securing passwords, so why do you think it's not as secure as using SHA512?

Comment: I'm not talking about secure, I'm talking about supported. At least two out of the three applications that are supposed to verify my generated hashes do not support bcrypt, so it is really useless to me. No matter how secure. There is a world outside of PHP.

Comment: Then perhaps you should have indicated that you needed something compatible with external (non-PHP) applications in your question... everything in your question indicated that you wanted a PHP solution for a hash and verify

Comment: Fixed. Fixed. Fixed.